# How to authorize docker so docker pull can get private images inside a systemd service?

Tags: systemd, coreos

I want docker to pull my private images inside the systemd service, so I authorize it by login into the shell of `core` user and run `docker authorize`. However, I can see that when systemd start the service and invoke docker, it is not authorized, so it can't find my private images.

What is the correct way to authorize docker so it can pull private images when being executed by systemd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://coreos.com/docs/launching-containers/building/registry-authentication/

You need to 1. Drop a dockercfg on disk with cloudconfig and 2. Tell your unit to run as the core user.